# STA driver support for b43xx wireless broken again

Tags: broadcom

Once again the STA driver doesn't work for b43xx cards in Ubuntu 11.04.  I know it's a kernel issue.  I want to understand why it keeps getting broken?  I can never upgrade with confidence that I'll have network connectivity when I finish.  It worked fine in 10.04 and 10.10.  Why can't you guys get this stable?

Comment: I was under the impression that this card was now supported by opensource drivers.

Comment: This isn't a flame attempt. In my experience you *have* to wait at least two weeks after a release before you can safely expect WiFi to work OOTB. I'm still waiting on a fix in 10.10 because Ubuntu detects my chipset incorrectly. This is easily fixed by blacklisting modules but the moral is: Wait for the *real* beta testers to sort out potential problems for you before you make the leap. In the case of 11.04, I'd extend that to 6 weeks due to the change to Unity wholesale, and the problems we're seeing here and elsewhere.

Comment: Why does Wifi work with these during the installation of the OS, yet stop working once it's installed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this will be closed soon as argumentative or flame/trolling, but a better way to do your updates would be to test it out on live CD before installing. And as for kernel updates, that's why GRUB lets you choose old kernels in case the new one doesn't work properly for you.

Also the STA driver is closed source. The community has no control over it, it's up to Broadcom to fix it, so you'd be better of complaining to them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is fixed or was yesterday when I installed it for my broadcom wifi

You may have to reinstall the sta driver

You could in a terminal try the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Not much more than that will be necessary

As the other answer says Ubuntu do not make the STA driver but Broadcom do. As kernels change so do the drivers at Broadcom.

There is an excellent guide for installing Broadcom wifi drivers here which will also help if you are off line as they give you a how to  with no internet access if like me a few times you are stuck with no wired connection and you have broken the wifi:

[UBUNTU WIFI GUIDE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)